# Making update-persistent changes to initrd in CentOS

Tags: centos, kernel, yum, initramfs, dracut

I am booting a CentOS image via NFS, which requires a custom `initramfs` from `dracut`, with some extra modules. I want the kernel to get updated normally, using `yum update`. This will automatically generate a new `initramfs` each time the kernel is updated, which doesn't include any of my extra modules.

- How/when does `yum update` generate the new `initramfs`?
- Can the system be configured so that `yum update` includes my custom modules every time?

The goal is to avoid needing `yum update` + `dracut -m "etc" name.img kernel.ver` every time we update, since there will be many different system images that we need to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused by dracut lately...

> How/when does yum update generate the new initramfs?

AFAIK, there's posttrans section in kernel.rpm.  such as

`%{_sbindir}/new-kernel-pkg --package kernel%{?-v:-%{-v*}} --mkinitrd --dracut --depmod --update %{KVRA}%{?-v:.%{-v*}}`

In another word, just after all other work done in a kernel package, a new initrd is generated.

> Can the system be configured so that yum update includes my custom modules every time?

yes, please refer to dracut doc https://linux.die.net/man/5/dracut.conf